# Finding contours based on sharp color transition

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I'm new to OpenCV, and trying different approaches to extract traffic signs from an image. Currently I'm using a common approach with `B&W` ⇒ `Blur` ⇒ `Canny` ⇒ `findContours` and some shape matching to separate Triangles, Rectangles and Circles in the image, but this method doesn't work very well.

All the OpenCV edge detection examples I found online use B&W image as input, while it seems to me that it would be better to detect the interesting areas of the input image by identifying sharp color transitions, since most traffic signs have some kind of a "frame" - e.g. red-to-white transition, black-to-white transition, black-to-yellow transition, white-to-blue transition etc.

Is there an easy way to detect edges based on such two-color combinations in OpenCV? Or I would have to convert the input image to HSV, then filter out the interesting colours and convert to grayscale (which again may become less efficient since the color information would be lost).

Comment: take a look at [squares.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp) and [this tutorial based on squares.cpp](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/detecting-simple-shapes-in-an-image/)

Comment: @sturkmen, thanks I can already identify shapes, the question is about different problem. The color information is discarded in the tutorial (e.g. the Canny edge detector doesn't differentiate shape colors), while I'm asking about a method to detect edges based on two known adjacent colors

Comment: i give squares.cpp first focus on [these lines](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp#L59-L65)

Comment: seems this approach may actually be something that HOG and SVM does...

Comment: Working with color and color edges in outdoor settings with varying lighting is not nearly as easy or fun as it sounds. Is there any easy way to detect edges? Yes. Are they the edges you'll expect for a nice, clean geometric figure? Not as often as you'd like.